# Split a macro enabled file as separate files based on the column values

Tags: excel, vba, input, output

Imagine I have a file that already has macros in it which is applied to the data. I want to split that file into multiple files based on the region column such a way that I have to keep all the macro functions in that split files also from the original file. Please tell me the way to do it in VBA.

```
Sub SplitEachWorksheet()
    Dim FPath As String
    FPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        ws.Copy
        Application.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, 
    Filename:=FPath & "\" & ws.Name & ".xlsx"
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    Next

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

But I don't know-how to split by keeping macro functionalities from original file. please tell me how to do that.

Comment: Please do not post your code in a comment. Include it in your question instead, as explained in the introduction to the site. As you can see it does not get formatted correctly and just creates a mess in the comments.

Comment: Please use 3 tick characters above and under your code, not 3 single quote characters ...

Comment: @PeterPesch I think now the format of code is clear right?

Comment: @PeterPesch yes it's done please have a look.

Comment: Yes, now it is clear

Comment: @PeterPesch if you know the answer please drop the code or algorithm in answers.

Comment: Still working on it. Easiest way might be to start by copying the file, but I don't like that approach ... Trying to find some way which works and is easy to understand/change/maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do that in VBA, I would suggest you write code to:

- Find all the values from the Region column
- For each region:

  - Make a full copy of the original file (including the macro's)
  - Delete all rows which don't belong to that region

---

You'll have to put the macro which does the splitting and copying in a separate workbook.
I will assume that the region is in the first column of the first Sheet, and that all relevant data is on the first sheet. You will have to change that in the code to match the position in your workbook
And I assume that the original workbook is not opened. You may want to close it in your code.

```
Sub kopieer()
    Dim macro_wb As Workbook
    Dim macro_ws As Worksheet

    Dim orig_wb As Workbook
    Dim orig_ws As Worksheet
    Dim orig_range As Range
    Dim origpath As String
    Dim origname As String

    Dim region_wb As Workbook
    Dim region_ws As Worksheet
    Dim region As String
    Dim region_wb_name As String
    Dim region_row As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    origname = "D:\Oefen\test\Test_0.xlsm"

    ' Use this workbook to  find the regions
    Set macro_wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set macro_sheet = Sheet1
    macro_sheet.Cells.Clear

    Set orig_wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=origname)
    origpath = orig_wb.Path
    ' Assuming the region is in first column of first Sheet
    Set orig_ws = orig_wb.Sheets(1)
    Set orig_range = orig_ws.Range([A2], [A2].End(xlDown))
    orig_range.Copy (Sheet1.[A1])
    orig_wb.Close

    ' Now we have all regions in column 1 of first sheet
    Sheet1.Range([A1], [A1].End(xlDown)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

    ' loop throught the regions
    For row = 1 To Sheet1.[A1].End(xlDown).row
        region = Sheet1.Cells(row, 1)
        ' Make a full copy of the original file (including the macro's)
        region_wb_name = origpath + "\" + region + ".xlsm"
        FileCopy origname, region_wb_name
        ' Delete all rows which don't belong to that region
        Set region_wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(region_wb_name)
        Set region_ws = region_wb.Sheets(1)
        ' We are deleting rows, so we should start at the bottom
        For region_row = region_ws.[A2].End(xlDown).row To 2 Step -1
            If region_ws.Cells(region_row, 1).Value <> region Then
                region_ws.Rows(region_row).Delete
            End If
        Next region_row
        region_wb.Save
        region_wb.Close
    Next row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: Why not? It does give an algorithm which answers the question - without giving away any code. And the algorithm could help the topic starter to write his own code.